# Unable to Pull messages from a pubsub topic/subscription from another project

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am new to GCP. My Use case involves reading(PULL) the data from multiple pub-sub subscriptions present in multiple different projects say (A, B, C) to another project say D.
I read the documentation for access control in pub-sub. Following that, I tried binding service accounts of project A, B, C (which has publisher/subscriber role) to the topic that is present on project D. After this I tried to pull messages from a subscription present in project A, using "gcloud" command from project D ("gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull [SUBSCRIPTION_NAME_IN_PROJECT_A"), and I am still not able to fetch the result and getting an error as  "NOT_FOUND: Resource not found".

Can somebody please help me as how to achieve cross-project communication in pub-sub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the project with the flag `--project`. If you do not then it looks for the subscription in the same project you are running the command. More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/subscriptions/pull)

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull <subs-name project A> --project=<projectId A>
```